# Spacewalk (satellite) activation refresh child channels on client

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

We have a (spacewalk) rhn satellite server running and several hundred machines registered with it with a few activation keys. Each of these keys have one or more child channels. We need to know how to 'refresh' the registration so that the clients can have any new child channels that we add to be available to them. We would like to be able to write a script that will check the 'currentness' of its registration automatically on a regular basis, but can't work out how to do it without re-registering the machine which would leave too many defunct profiles on the server side. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The activiation key is only used when the system is registered.  If you want to change the child channels for a system or systems, you can manage them via the SSM in the UI to do this, or via the API.

The only way to use an activation key to manage channels after registration is to re-register the system with the same activation key.